# Breeze Delete Parent with Guid PK and Children are Modified

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework, breeze

I am trying to delete both the parent and the children entities in an Angular/Breeze application.

The backing store is a code-first Entity Framework.

The entities are as follows:

```
public class Ingredient
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<IngredientDescription> Descriptions { get; set; }

}

public class IngredientDescription
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid IngredientId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IngredientId")]
    public virtual Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Culture { get; set; }
}
```

When I delete the Ingredient, I need to delete the IngredientDescription.  I have tried doing it both ways, where I delete either first (children, then parent or parent, then children).

Whenever I delete the Ingredient (parent), Breeze is setting the children IngredientDescription.IngredientId to Guid.Empty or {0000-0000-...}.  This is causing the children entities to a state of Modified (as opposed to the Deleted I had already set them).

I have tried everything I can think of to get this to work from the clientside code.  I have gotten it to work by previewing the changes in the controller and re-marking it as Deleted.  But, I'd like to just get it to work from the clientside.

I don't have to have cascading deletes, just if I delete it, to prevent Breeze from modifying it from Deleted to Modified.

My clientside function is as below:

```
        function removeIngredient(ingredient) {

        var descriptions = ingredient.descriptions;

        for (var d = 0; d < ingredient.descriptions.length; d++) {
            var thisDescription = ingredient.descriptions[d];
            thisDescription.entityAspect.setDeleted();
        }

        ingredient.entityAspect.setDeleted();

    }
```

Any thoughts on how I can keep Breeze from marking the child objects as Modified after I have already marked them as Deleted?

Below is an image of where the child's EntityState is being set to modified from the removeFromRelations call.

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem was in the loop that deletes the children

```
for (var d = 0; d < ingredient.descriptions.length; d++) {
    var thisDescription = ingredient.descriptions[d];
    thisDescription.entityAspect.setDeleted();
}
```

By setting the record to Deleted via setDeleted(), the record is being removed from the array.  So, records were getting skipped for deletion and then when attempting to save the parent the FK violation was coming up.

I changed the function as below with a while length > 0

```
    function removeIngredient(ingredient) {
        while (ingredient.descriptions.length > 0) {
            ingredient.descriptions[0].entityAspect.setDeleted();
        }

        ingredient.entityAspect.setDeleted();

    }
```

Comment: I had exactly the same problem - if I had more than one child, I would get a foreign key violation because some of the children were skipped. This solved the problem for me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've just retested Breeze's deletion logic ( on breeze version 1.5.0) to try to confirm your issue, and have been unable to repro the behavior you see.  Just to recap, the order in which you perform deletions does matter.

- Delete parent then delete children

  - This will mark the parent as **deleted** and will force the update of the children's foreign keys to either null or the default value of the key depending on whether the foreign key property is nullable or not. The one exception to this rule is that breeze will never attempt to modify a primary key, so if the foreign key of the child is also part of the primary key then breeze will not attempt to modify it.
  - All child navigation properties will now return either empty arrays or null depending on whether the navigation property is scalar or not.   At this point each of the children will marked as **modified**, as a result of the foreign key change.
  - Then the children will each be marked **deleted**.
- Delete children then parent ( recommended)

  - The children will each be marked **deleted**. Foreign keys will NOT change but the corresponding navigation property will return null, instead of the returning the parent. At this point all of the parent's navigation properties that previously returned these children will now return either null or an empty array.
  - The parent is marked deleted.  No change is made to any of its children ( because it has none at this point).

I have been unable to repro a case where an entity is set to an entity state of modified after it has been deleted.  However, this may have been a bug in an earlier version of Breeze, so please try your test with the latest version.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for the taking the time to look into this.  We are using the following breeze version:  
  
version: "1.5.0",  
metadataVersion: "1.0.5"  

I have added a image to the original post where the child entity is being set to modified.  Please let me know if this is helpful or not.  Please let me know what else I can do to help you help me.  
  
Do you think it has something to do with the key type being a Guid?  
  
Thanks again.

Comment: I can't seem to repro your issue. I've tried with both Guids and Ints. The only difference in my model is that my foreign keys are nullable and it sounds like yours are not. Does your ingredientDescription itself have children?  If you can repro this with the DocCode model in breeze.js samples I can fix it.  The closest objects in DocCode will be the Customer and Orders entities.  Customer's key is a guid and it has an 'orders' property where every order has the customer's CustomerID as a foreign key.